# ecs-cli compose service up Tasks Keep Getting Stopped

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, docker, amazon-ecs

We are deploying our Docker images through ECS and creating the cluster is working just fine with the following command.

```
ecs-cli up --force --keypair <redacted> --capability-iam --size 1 --instance-type t2.large
```

Following that we already have a repository with our latest code pushed to it. So here is our docker file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: web:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    mem_limit: 7984000
    links:
      - start_dependencies
    depends_on:
      - start_dependencies
  seed-web:
    image: web:seed-latest
    links:
      - start_dependencies
    depends_on:
      - start_dependencies
  db-web:
    # below example references the latest mongo image on docker hub
    image: mongo:3.4.2
  start_dependencies:
    image: web/wait-for-dependencies
    links:
      - db-web
    depends_on:
      - db-web
    command: db-web:27017
```

Bringing up the service with this command:

```
ecs-cli compose service up --deployment-min-healthy-percent 0 && success=1
```

But after starting multiple tasks the following output is displayed:

```
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option...           option name=networks
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=db-web
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name="depends_on" service name=seed-web
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=seed-web
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name="depends_on" service name="start_dependencies"
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name="start_dependencies"
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name="depends_on" service name=web
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=networks service name=web
INFO[0001] Using ECS task definition                     TaskDefinition="web:23"
INFO[0001] Created an ECS service                        deployment-min-healthy-percent=0 service=web taskDefinition="web:23"
INFO[0001] Updated ECS service successfully              deployment-min-healthy-percent=0 desiredCount=1 serviceName=web
INFO[0016] (service web) has started 1 tasks: (task 89ceda24-dd92-42ab-b290-ec5aa1837206).  timestamp=2018-02-04 09:49:06 +0000 UTC
INFO[0062] (service web) has started 1 tasks: (task 508924a3-1718-4564-8fb8-b95b846597cf).  timestamp=2018-02-04 09:49:49 +0000 UTC
INFO[0137] (service web) has started 1 tasks: (task 56c2f95b-d461-4e1f-ac66-8d36feae39b2).  timestamp=2018-02-04 09:51:07 +0000 UTC
INFO[0182] (service web) has started 1 tasks: (task 581d9318-212a-4e2d-b439-66378918e715).  timestamp=2018-02-04 09:51:51 +0000 UTC
INFO[0228] (service web) has started 1 tasks: (task 8db1f7a0-8217-4f85-ad41-08c4d430cd35).  timestamp=2018-02-04 09:52:34 +0000 UTC
INFO[0273] (service web) has started 1 tasks: (task 824f4aba-10b1-4197-95d0-afe59e3ced41).  timestamp=2018-02-04 09:53:19 +0000 UTC
INFO[0303] (service web) has started 1 tasks: (task cf532423-9618-4a85-aeb4-18de19962bcc).  timestamp=2018-02-04 09:54:04 +0000 UTC
FATA[0303] Deployment has not completed: Running count has not changed for 5.00 minutes
```

I tried setting up cloud watch logging but I got no reports. How do I get the deployment to complete? We are deploying a Node+Express, MongoDB app.

Comment: To me, it looks like your tasks are crashing (or otherwise being preventing from entering into `RUNNING` mode, hence the multiple attempts). Have you checked your container logs?

Comment: No I haven't checked the logs. Where would those logs be located?

Comment: On the box, `docker logs <container>`

Comment: Get the container id with `docker ps`, then see the logs with `docker logs CONTAINER_ID`.